# Problem with simple Client/Server, file gets printed wrong

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

Basically, the server needs to print into a file a structure filled by the client, both client and server should stop when message.fine == 1. The problem is that every time the file is created, it gets filled with thousands of zero, which indicates that the read and write function didn't work correctly. Could you pls help me with this problem?

This is the client:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct Data 
{
    int a;
    float b;
    int fine;
    int risultato;
};

int main()
{   
    int sock;
    struct Data message, response;
    message.fine = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(6869);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));

    while(message.fine != 1)
    {   
        printf("\nInsert an integer number:");
        scanf("%d", &message.a);
        printf("\nInsert a float number:");
        scanf("%f", &message.b);
        printf("\nIs this the final message? (0 = no, 1 = yes)\n");
        scanf("%d", &message.fine);


        write(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));
        read(sock, &response, sizeof(struct Data));

        if(response.risultato == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nServer returned Writing Error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if(response.risultato == 1)
        {
            printf("\nSuccess in Operation\n");
        }
    }
    close(sock);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And this is the server:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct Data 
{
    int a;
    float b;
    int fine;
    int risultato;
};



void * handler(void * args)
{
    struct Data message;    
    int sock = *(int *)args;
    FILE *fp;

     if(!(fp = fopen("result.txt", "a")))
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in opening file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    while(1)
    {

        read(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));

        printf("%d, %f, %d", message.a, message.b, message.fine);

        if(fprintf(fp,"\n[%d] [%.2f]\n", message.a, message.b) < 0)
        {
            message.risultato = -1;
        }
        else{
            message.risultato = 1;
        }

        if(message.fine == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        write(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));

    }
    fclose(fp);
    close(sock);
    free(args);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main()
{
    int sock, client_sock;
    int * new_sock;

    pthread_t tid;

    struct sockaddr_in address, client_address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(6869);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    socklen_t sock_len = (socklen_t)sizeof(address);


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sock_len);

    listen(sock, 3);

    while(1)
    {
       new_sock = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
       sock_len = sizeof(client_address);
       client_sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &sock_len); 
       *new_sock = client_sock;       
       pthread_create(&tid, NULL, handler, (void *)new_sock);
       pthread_detach(tid);
    }

}
```

The actual result should be the numbers in message.a and message.b printed sequentially on the file.

Comment: Why do you allocate a `new_sock` on every iteration?

Comment: Why don't you check the return values of `read` and `write`?

Comment: I'll check the return value of read and write, but i don't think that will solve the problem...

Comment: `read()` does not guarantee that it will return `sizeof(struct Data)` bytes. Hence you'll have to modify your code to perform as many `read()`'s as necessary until you have accumulated one message.

Comment: You have no idea how many bytes you either `read()` or `write()`.  Those calls return a value for a reason.  TCP connections are a stream, and you can read/write **any** number of bytes.  You "don't think that will solve the problem", but then you're the one asking your question because you can't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bruno and @Jay for the help and all the suggestions. I arranged the read part like this:

```
do{

   res = read(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));

  }while(res < sizeof(struct Data));
```

same thing for the write, and now it works!

P.S. I noticed that if i don't flush the file stream after the fprintf was succesfull, the file doesn't gets printed, it prints it after the loop break. Why does this happen?

Comment: I am not sure if this will work in all cases. For Ex: If we consider int and float to be 4 bytes each, then sizeof(struct Data) will be 16. But, let's say, you received 4 bytes on first read call, then you need pass read(sock, &message+4, (16-4) in the second call, else you will be overwriting on the previously read data.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that every time the file is created, it gets filled with thousands of zero, which indicates that the read and write function didn't work correctly

**Warning** you use SOCK_STREAM, you do not have the guaranty to read all the expected bytes on *one* read.

In the server you need to check the result of

```
   read(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));
```

to break on error or read again while all if is not read, else when nothing is read or if you read less than the expected size *message* is totally or partially unchanged or unset if it was at the first loop and you have a *chance* to loop up to the end of the times, and of course the values you print in the file are also unchanged or invalid.

The probable scenario you had was : during the exchanges (may be at the first) in the server *read* doesn't read all the struct, because of that `message.fine` is not set to 1 and some other values are unset too, because `message.fine != 1` you loop again and you read again but from the unread bytes rather that from the beginning of the struct, so even you read `sizeof(Data)` bytes that time the struct is not well populated, and again `message.fine` is not set to 1 and the other attributes not set with a correct value, etc and at a moment there is nothing to read and you loop indefinitely because *message* stay unchanged.

Of course I encourage you to also check the result of the *write*, and you have the same problem when you read in your client

Comment: Ty for the suggestion, but i don't think that solves the problem

Comment: ok i'll try it and see if it works, i'm still open for other solutions btw

Comment: @St3veR0nix I you read on a **stream**, you don't read blocks with a fixed size like with UDP. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your client/server side read code has to be modified to check for return value of read call. Do remember that, when you use SOCK_STREAM, all the data is sent is sent and received as a stream (not as Datagrams) causing data of subsequent sends to be put together and similarly not necessitating all of data of a single send to be received in one go on the other side.

Modified code snippet of server (Just a pseudo code), please check and modify your original code appropriately:

```
while(1)
{
    int res_bytes = 0;
    int res = 0;
    while (res_bytes < sizeof(struct Data))
    {
        res = read(sock, &message+res_bytes, (sizeof(struct Data) - res_bytes));
        if ((res == 0) || (res == -1))
        {
            printf("read returned an error, returning");
            return;
        }
        res_bytes = res_bytes + res;
    }

    printf("%d, %f, %d", message.a, message.b, message.fine);

    if(fprintf(fp,"\n[%d] [%.2f]\n", message.a, message.b) < 0)
    {
        message.risultato = -1;
    }
    else{
        message.risultato = 1;
    }

    if(message.fine == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    res = write(sock, &message, sizeof(struct Data));
    if ((res == 0) || (res == -1))
    {
       printf("Error while writing");
       return;
    }
}
```